# Hiding, then showing status bar loses background - iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistatusbar

I am presenting from a view controller with a visible status bar to a view controller with a hidden status bar, then dismissing it. Upon dismissing, the status bar doesn't have my navigation bar's background color anymore - it's completely transparent.

I'm using `View controller-based status bar appearance - NO` and hiding and showing the navigation bar in each view controller with:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden{}
```

I believe the problem lies with the navigation bar not resizing correctly when the status bar comes back.

This issue is only prevalent on iOS 7.0 and 7.1.